# Collision of hypothetical Tachyon with normal particle?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws, faster-than-light, tachyon

If we are dealing in one dimension, what will happen if a hypothetical particle Tachyon (pure imaginary rest mass, $v>c$ and real momentum & total relativistic energy)? Will it interact with the normal particle, and is it legal to apply the relativistic momentum and energy conservation in dealing with such a problem?

Comment: Tachyons are just a broad category of particles, there is nothing in the definition of tachyons that detail their interactions. If you want to know what happens, you'll have to ask about a specific model.

Comment: @Slereah I meant only from momentum and energy conservation laws, as non-quantum mechanics exist nor classification. I tried to solve the equations I get every time different answer. I just want to see if anyone solved these two equations for a tachyon with a normal particle or no?

Answer (score 2):

From  good old [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon),

> Even an electrically neutral tachyon would be expected to lose energy
> via gravitational Cherenkov radiation (unless gravitons are themselves
> tachyons), because it has a gravitational mass, and therefore
> increases in speed as it travels, as described above. If the tachyon
> interacts with any other particles, it can also radiate Cherenkov
> energy into those particles.

Be warned - that same article mentions that the term "tachyon" is now used coloquially when some physicists are 'playing around' with theoretical particles having imaginary mass even tho' not moving at  $v > c$ .